# Apache Cassandra cqlsh --keyspace being ignored

Tags: docker, cassandra, cqlsh

We are using Apache Cassandra 3.11.2, with `cqlsh` 5.0.1. I am recreating and populating some tables by passing a file to the `cqlsh` command, in which I have multiple `SOURCE` statements for the various tables I am creating and populating. None of the files have hard-coded keyspaces for the tables, so I am passing them in on the command line with the `--keyspace` parameter.

`SOURCE 'favorite-destinations-table-drop.cql';
SOURCE 'favorite-destinations-table-create.cql';
...`

The weird thing is, if I run this locally on my Windows machine, it works fine. If I run this locally on a Cassandra Docker container, it also works fine. However, if I run it from a Linux Docker comtainer that has `cqlsh` installed (also version 5.0.1), talking to a Docker container that has Cassandra 3.11.2 installed, I get error messages that I am not specifying a keyspace, even though it's on the command line. I even put a `USE` statement in the file that sources the CQL files, and it's still giving me this error:

`command = cqlsh --cqlversion 3.4.4 --file w2_int_test-database-init-populate.cql --keyspace w2_integration_test cassandra-0.cassandra.w3-rre-system.svc.cluster.local 9042
favorite-destinations-table-drop.cql:2:InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename"
favorite-destinations-table-create.cql:16:InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename"
...`

We had to add the `--cqlversion 3.4.4` to the command line because we were getting weird version mismatch errors. So I'm not sure if this is related in any way.

The only thing that seems to be different is that in the failing execution, the server is on a different server than where we are running `cqlsh` from. When it works, they are on the same server.

Comment: have you tried to change *.cql files?

Comment: you need to modify the inner cql files ..either put USE  or specify keyspac.table

Comment: Thanks, I tried `USE` right before the `SOURCE` statements, but that didn't work. I don't want to hard-code the keyspace in the sourced CQL files, because then I can only use them for one keyspace, and we use multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got around this problem, without hard-coding the keyspace in the sourced CQL files, was to create a script that reads the list of files to source, and runs `cqlsh` for each of them with the keyspace specified on the command line. Seems to me like `SOURCE` doesn't work very well in a remote environment (since this all works locally).